# ¿Cómo pedir la fecha con formato aaaammdd por teclado?

Tags: c

Mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int numero, aaaa, mm, dd;
    printf("Introduzca el numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    return 0;
}
```

En verdad me quedé congelado, no se como seguir el programa, si alguien me ayuda se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Olvida años, meses, días, y olvida el lenguaje c... digamos que tienes un número X, por ejemplo, 134567... y quieres mostrar cuantos _"miles"_  representa, ¿cómo podrías _extraer_ el 134 de ese número? Hazlo en papel... primero es el desarrollo de la solución dentro de tu mente, luego la programación. Este ejercicio está diseñado para desarrollar tu lógica, no para enseñarte a programar, por tanto, no veo la forma de ayudarte si te doy el código.

Answer (score 1):

> > ¿Cómo pedir la fecha con formato aaaammdd por teclado?

Debes pedir 3 entradas de datos en una misma llamada a `scanf`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int year, month, day;
    printf("Ingrese el anio, mes, dia: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &year, &month, &day);
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", year, month, day);
    return 0;
}
```

Entonces el usuario simplemente ingresa el año, día y mes separado por espacios.

Ejemplo:

```c
Ingrese el anio, mes, dia:
> 2014 10 10
```

También puedes darle un formato en especifico al momento de pedir la fecha:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int year, month, day;
    printf("Ingrese una fecha con formato yyyy/mm/dd: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &year, &month, &day);
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", year, month, day);
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso el delimitador no es un espacio, sino, el slash.

La intención de esta respuesta es darte una pista de como resolver el problema (no quiero hacer TODO el trabajo). A este código le falta validación, como por ejemplo, el día debe estar entre el rango de `1-31`. Esto te lo dejo de tarea :D

Answer (score -1):

Existe una libreria en windows para obtener la fecha y hora local actual, y funciones para darles un formato de salida en pantalla

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t tiempo = time(0);
    struct tm *tlocal = localtime(&tiempo);
    char output[128];
    
    strftime(output,128,"Fecha: %y/%m/%d \nHora: %H:%M:%S",tlocal);
    printf("%s\n",output);

    return 0;
}
```

este codigo lo saque de la siguiente pagina web [http://www.holamundo.es/lenguaje/c/articulos/fecha-hora-c.html#:~:text=Para%20obtener%20la%20fecha%20y,variable%20de%20tipo%20%22time_t%22](http://www.holamundo.es/lenguaje/c/articulos/fecha-hora-c.html#:%7E:text=Para%20obtener%20la%20fecha%20y,variable%20de%20tipo%20%22time_t%22).
leelo bien para documentarte mas sobre como funciona y los formatos posibles